# Deploy create-react-app with react-router to Godaddy routing issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I deployed my app in Godaddy using the files generated from "npm run build". When I access routes from the app, it works fine. However, when I refresh the app it gives me a 404 page not found error. I tried adding the .htaccess file, but it still doesn't work.

Here is the router code:

```
       <Router>
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Splash} />
    <Route path="/signin" component={SignInView} />
    <Route path="/signup" component={SignUpView} />
    <Route path="/dashboard" render={() => (<TabbedView tabIndex={0} {...this.props} />)} />
    <Route path="/activities-dashboard" render={() => (<TabbedView tabIndex={1} {...this.props} />)} />
    <Route path="/new-activity" render={() => (<TabbedView tabIndex={2} {...this.props} />)} />
    <Route path="/profile" render={() => (<TabbedView tabIndex={3} {...this.props} />)} />
    <Route path="/activities/:value" component={CircularList} />
  </div>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 2):

create a file .htaccess

using terminal  'nano .htaccess'
after create file. paste the below code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Save it

then upload this file in public_html folder
by using  godaddy file manger

Answer (score 1):

If you are using  instead of  you get 404 when you refresh it manually because the browser is trying to make a call to request a pages which does not exist.

You can have a look at this interesting link which will help you to understand better:

[React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writting manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually)