# How to fix whitescreen for reactJS on goDaddy

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to deploy a react application to a godaddy hosted website. The website can be found at [mattdambra.com](https://mattdambra.com), and the repository exists at [github.com//superrmatt/react-portfolio](https://github.com/superrmatt/react-portfolio).

The issue I have is the application works perfectly fine on my PC, phone, other people's PCs, etc. when running npm start. But just shows a white screen on the godaddy site. I get the following console statements: [image: console errors]
I have placed the build files into /public/html in cpanel/godaddy.

I have been at this for days if not over a week now. I have scoured everything piece by piece and reviewed anything that can be found online, to no avail. The most common solution I saw for others appeared to be to change the `homepage` in `package.json` to `"."`. However, this made no difference for my situation.

package.json:

```
{
  "homepage": "http://mattdambra.com/mattdambra-react/",
  "name": "mattdambra-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.3",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-pdf": "^4.1.0",
    "react-perf-devtool": "^3.1.8",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.7.16",
    "react-social-badge": "^1.0.6"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.13.0",
    "npm": "6.12.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "2.0.4",
    "gh-pages": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Not quite sure what I am doing with .htaccess, this is a sample I had gotten from a tutorial, and the way it was worded made it seem like it should be good for anything. As you will read below, self taught and am still learning/figuring out.
Let me know if anything is needed or desired. My react knowledge is almost entirely self taught, so I may not be doing things to convention, or even properly at all! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-----------UPDATE----------
after implementing some changes to my .htaccess file (see below), I am now getting a number of 404 errors associated with particular files (again, see below), however, the website still loads with a blank screen.

new .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
 </IfModule>
```

associated console errors:
[image: console_errors_after_htacess_update]

Comment: You are using moz for seo, it may be tracking users and therefore disabled by firefox. If you check it in chrome you will get 404 errors. What I can suggest is that you try uploading a simple react project before deploying your current project, this will help you in debugging the issue.

Comment: Make sure that you have deployed your build version to right directory i.e. `mattdambra.com/mattdambra-react` and also configured .htaccess file correctly. You can add the content of the .htaccess file in your question so we can look if everything is correct.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that to check things out. This one involves three pages, it is a simple portfolio, as I imagine you have guessed by now. .htaccess is something I actually know very little about, I have a sample file, I'm going to be bold and guess that is my main problem. Added to question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49967275/deploy-create-react-app-with-react-router-to-godaddy-routing-issue

Comment: @ksav I implemented the .htaccess on that link and now am getting a number of 404s. (posted them in original question). To me, this seems like progress! thanks!